# Get the ranges and color associated with it - Chroma.js

Tags: javascript, colors

I've a certain requirement where in user will input the color and the values.

I'm using [chroma.js](http://gka.github.io/chroma.js/), say for example

```
var scale = chroma.scale(['color1','color2','color3']).domain([0,3,10,80,100]);
```

So now I've 3 user defined color and muliple values.  I'm using the chroma.js to get the color out of it for the particular value.

```
scale(10).hex() // Will give me a #color
```

My Question is,  I need something like

```
0 - 30 = color1
30 - 65 = color2
65 - 100 = color3
```

Please help me how to achieve this using chroma.js.  Hope my question is clear.

Comment: do you need a range or a color for a specific value?

Comment: I need range and color.  Take choropleth in map as example.  I need to show a legend with range's and color.

Answer (score 1):

I think [scale.classes](http://gka.github.io/chroma.js/#scale-classes) is exactly what you want:

```js
chroma.scale(['red','blue','green'])
    .domain([0,100])
    .classes([0,33,65,100])
```

Comment: Chroma docs say no need to use `domain` if using `classes`  [https://github.com/gka/chroma.js/issues/198](https://github.com/gka/chroma.js/issues/198)